# "No question of",paired with "either/or"

Tags: negative-polarity-items, either-or

Even after reviewing other "either/or" questions in relation to a negative preceding them, the negatives themselves being almost exclusively verbs, I am still a bit conflicted about the following statement:

"It is accepted by both parties that there is no question of Charlesco’s  email of 29 October constituting either (a) a breach of contract, or (b) duress by Charlesco."

Would the "no question of" act as a negative, making (a)the breach and (b)duress both an impossibility, or does it mean that it is impossible for just (a), or (b) alone to exist?

Is it just a sentence so ambiguous that there is no clear way of interpreting it?

Thanks to anyone for their time...

Comment: Neither. *There is no question of* here means *it surely is the case that*. (Disclaimer: this is not legal advice.)

Answer (score 2):

*"It is accepted by both parties that there is no question of Charlesco’s email of 29 October constituting either (a) a breach of contract, or (b) duress by Charlesco."*

This means:

> Both sides have accepted the following observation: The email does not constitute a breach of contract; and the email does not constitute duress.

Comment: Absolutely. If either party thought that the email _might_ have constituted breach of contract there would have been _some_ question of the email constituting breach of contract. The same thing would apply to duress. The fact that both parties accept that there is no question that it constitutes _either_ one _or_ the other means that neither party is claiming breach of contract and neither party is claiming duress (as far as this email is concerned anyway).